# SQLite Error - misuse of aggregate: sum()

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Hi I'm getting misuse of aggregate: sum() error for the follwing query. Whats wrong with this.

```
> Select storeid, supplierid, ordernumber, inwardnumber, returnid,
> taxinvoiceno, ordervalue, sum(CASHPAID) as 'CASHPAID', balancedue,
> paidamt, paiddate, sum(ADJUSTMENT) as
> ADJUSTMENT,ordervalue+sum(ADJUSTMENT) as total from
> supplierpaymentstabledb where storeid = 10008 and total!=CASHPAID
> group by inwardnumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of good practice, you should put all the non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause.  Then, conditions on the aggregated columns should be in a `having` clause, not a `where` clause:

```
Select storeid, supplierid, ordernumber, inwardnumber, returnid,
       taxinvoiceno, ordervalue, sum(CASHPAID) as CASHPAID, balancedue,
       paidamt, paiddate, sum(ADJUSTMENT) as ADJUSTMENT, 
       ordervalue + sum(ADJUSTMENT) as total
from supplierpaymentstabledb
where storeid = 10008 
group by storeid, supplierid, ordernumber, inwardnumber, returnid,
         taxinvoiceno, ordervalue, balancedue,
         paidamt, paiddate
having total <> CASHPAID;
```

Comment: I want to group by inwardnumber only. Can I do it?

Comment: @Seenu69 In the select list you can have either aggregates or grouping columns. The only exception I'm aware of is MySQL with their "Extended Group By". If you want to group only on one column the other have to be aggregates. You can use min(col) or max(col) for the other non-grouping columns (but the sum() of course).

Comment: @Seenu69 . . . Yes, but you need to figure out what you want in the other columns (if you need them at all).